# How can I vertically align a font-awesome input checkbox with its label?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm using font-awesome in place of default checkboxes and they are not vertically aligned with their labels. How can I either vertically align them or position the label without moving the checkbox itself?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-green" id="authorized">
    <label for="authorized">I am authorized to work in the United States.</label>
</div>
<div class="row margin-top-12">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-green" id="drugs">
    <label for="drugs">I am not currently using illegal drugs.</label>
</div>
<div class="row margin-top-12">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-green" id="felony">
    <label for="felony">I have not been convicted of a felony.              </label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

.checkbox-green { display: none; }

.checkbox-green + label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 34px;
  width: 50px;
  color: $brand_green;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: "\f096";
}
.checkbox-green:hover + label:before { color: $brand_green--dark; }
.checkbox-green:checked + label:before { content: "\f046"; }
```

Codepen at http://codepen.io/3chordme/pen/pbRwgQ

EDIT: I would like the label and the checkbox to be vertically aligned along their center axes. Adding the style { vertical-align: middle } to the label does not work. Relative positioning of the label moves the text and the checkbox. Changing the font size of the checkbox or the text is not an option.

Comment: Technically they are vertically aligned. You just made the checkboxes bigger, and both are aligned bottom. Do you want them aligned center?

Comment: One way would be to use the same `font-size` of both `checkbox:before` and the `label`.

Comment: @disso Yes, I would like the checkbox icon and the label text to be vertically centered, so that they are aligned along their vertical axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `vertical-align: middle;` to  **.checkbox-green + label:before** that's it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to center them you need to do something like this. Note I'm not a CSS wizard so this may be a less than ideal solution.

CSS

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

.checkbox-green { display: none; }

.checkbox-green + label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 34px;
  width: 50px;
  color: $brand_green;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: "\f096";
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;

}
.checkbox-green:hover + label:before { color: $brand_green--dark; }
.checkbox-green:checked + label:before { content: "\f046"; }
```

Comment: This appears to be CSS, not JS, but it does in fact work! I'm actually getting the desired effect with or without the line-height modification, what do you mean "without collapsing"?

Comment: My mistake on the label. Fixed it. Looks like you updated your fiddle, so I can't say for sure, but I think I was playing with `position: absolute` which I think would need the line height. Definitely cut out any code you don't need though!

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to the label element.
It says the item to place it into the middle of each other.

Comment: That won't work. The "checkbox" is a pseudo element of the label.

Comment: I tested it before i answered, try that, it is work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below properties to `label::before` Pseudo selector, it will aligned vertically.

```
.checkbox-green + label::before{
     position:relative;
     top:12px;
 }
```